# How-to debug wp_ajax_* hook callback?

Tags: ajax

I'm currently developing a plugin that uses ajax functionality.

**Problem:** The callback isn't fired = no data gets processed.

```
if ( ! is_admin() )
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array( 'wpseAjaxClass', 'init' ), 10 );
```

Comment: Last time I had this issue was due to the callback function not actually being accessible during the AJAX request. For example, I buried the call to instantiate the class under a function like `is_single()`. It was called when the page was being viewed, but not when the AJAX request was made. I see that one of your comments says the code is part of the class. Any chance you can show the rest of the class?

Comment: @tollmanz Thanks for the comment. jQuery mobile loads everything with one request, so basically it's like a js-slider/-carousel. The `my_action_cb()` fn itself isn't hidden behind something. Just sits right in the middle of the class. As shown in the, the enqueue happens right in the `__construct()` of the class. I added a screenshot from the console. Please see Edit. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry to harp on this, but clearly the script cannot find the function. How is the class itself instantiated? When I have these issues, it's usually something little that I've missed. I'd love to look over the code to see if I could spot something.

Comment: Ok :) [Here's a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/JDD8LfLt). Tell me if the link isn't working. (And thanks for taking the time).

Comment: Looks like you might be mixing up your `wp_ajax` hooks. You have a no priv hook calling `neary_locations_cb` and the regular hook calling `nearby_parties_cb` (which is not defined). I would think you would want something like: http://pastebin.com/DY2ab1bB. Also, since I cannot see your actually JS, are you setting action to "nearby_locations" or "nearby-parties"?

Comment: To be more clear, I created this revised pastebin based on your pastebin: http://pastebin.com/r0Ud14aB

Comment: Oh...I see from the screenshot, your action is "nearby-parties". Your action associates "nearby-parties" with the "nearby_parties_cb" which is not defined in the class. If you define that function, you should be good to go.

Comment: Failure on my side: the class is quite big, got several ajax calls and functions and I reduced it to the minimum. I just deleted the wrong one. I'll update in a min. Actually there're - as seen in the screenshot - different calls. Point is that _no_ callback works

Comment: A stab in the dark , but have you tried adding the action call to the callback outside of the class? Normally, I don't wait till init to add ajax actions.

Comment: I already tried that and it seems that the failure is the hook. `wp_enqueue_scripts` doesn't work for this. I so far managed to move the function and action hooking process outside the class and hook it to `init`, which works. I now have to go through the hooks and check where I'm too late for this. In short: You hit the nail on the head. Could you write something about the hooks as answer, so I can mark it as solution later that day? Thanks (to both of you).

Comment: Update: For some reason I can get it working as a plain function in functions.php, not from the class. Please see the update. Maybe you've got an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was as **stupid** as **simple**: I wrapped the `init` for the class in a `! is_admin()` call. This successfully prevented the callback from beeing fired.

#### Rule for AJAX loading

- Load it in public
- Don't hide it behind a `! is_admin()` call.

#### The 2nd line from admin-ajax.php

```
define( 'WP_ADMIN', true );
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be something like this. Whenever I get the dreaded "0" response with WP AJAX, I instantly think that my function is inaccessible! Congrats on finding the issue and getting your life back ;)

Comment: :) Thanks for this comment. I'm currently more than angry about this issue and writing on wp-hackers :P

Comment: Also - don't pass a parameter called "action" inside your ajax callback routine - unless you want to seriously mess your own mind up!

Comment: @QStudio mind to clarify in an answer?

Comment: @kaiser - just a stupid mistake and venting.. I passed two "action" parameters and focused so hard I could not see it!

Comment: @QStudio haha! No worries. Happens to the best!