# Debug whats going on inside a function called from AJAX

Tags: custom-post-types, jquery, ajax, debug

I have a link on my post edit page (admin side) that calls up AJAX and jQuery to run a function inside my `functions.php` page.  The link is wired up and calling the jQuery but I can't seem to debug whats going on inside my function thats being called from jQuery.  I want the clicked link to delete custom metadata for the post (it is a custom post type) and then delete a file.

Here's the code with the delete function at the end:

```
//Add AJAX functionality to post.php to delete files
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue_scripts');
add_action('wp_ajax_delete_meta', 'delete_pdf_and_metadata');

//Add my custom JS to the header of admin
function my_admin_enqueue_scripts($hook) {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( 'post.php' != $hook )
        return;
    wp_register_script('my-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom/my-scripts.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('my-scripts');
    wp_localize_script('my-scripts', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

function delete_pdf_and_metadata() {

    global $post;

    //delete metadata
    $the_id = intval($_POST['the_id'] );
    $the_pdf = get_post_meta($post->ID, $the_id);

    delete_post_meta($post->ID, $the_id, $the_pdf['name']);

    //TODO Delete PDF 
}
```

Here's the jQuery call:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.delete_pdf').each(function(i,e) { //grab the class delete-pdf
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/delete-/, '');
        var li = $(this).closest('li');

        $(this).click(function(){

            $.post(ajaxurl, { action: 'delete_meta', the_id: id }, function(data){

                return id;
                });
        });

    });

});
```

Using FireBug all I see is for a response is 0.  What is the best way to debug what is happening inside my function `delete_pdf_and_metadata()` being called via jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to debug wp\_ajax\_\* hook callback?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/how-to-debug-wp-ajax-hook-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't echoing anything so you aren't going to get much of an AJAX response. All you are doing with AJAX, really, is loading a webpage with Javascript. If the page doesn't print anything, you don't see anything.  You don't need to return anything from AJAX but if you don't you will have a hard time working out whether your action was successful.

If you need to get information back, even for debugging, just `echo` it, or `var_dump` it. You will be able to see your `echo`ed or `var_dump`ed content with FireBug. Be aware that if your AJAX content is supposed to be something like JSON this debugging hack will break it.

Also, it kinda looks like you expect an ID to come back from your AJAX call. You will need to echo that in the `delete_pdf_and_metadata` function, or build a JSON object and echo that.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm able to echo anything from my `delete_pdf_and_metadata function` but the only thing that my jQuery does is return a response of 0.  I probably should make another question to try to get my ID passed into my function.  What you said helped tremendously though.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to catch things that FireBug doesn't:

```
function print_log( $msg, $title = '' )
{
    $error_dir = '/Applications/MAMP/logs/my.log';
    // or
    // $error_dir = '/home/user/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/my.log';
    $date = date('d.m.Y h:i:s'); // not used in this function
    $msg = print_r($msg,true);
    $log = $title."  |  ".$msg."\n";
    error_log( $log, 3, $error_dir );
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

The one thing is to simply add an `echo/var_dump/var_export/print_r()` around what you want to debug and then watch your Chrome DevTools, FireBug, etc. *Console* for the output.

If you want to print it directly on the screen then wrap around an `exit()` and you'll get *only* this part back.

Answer (score 0):

If you be experienced enough, write a database-logger. This could be a simple class with a databse connection and some read/write/update methods

```
class DB_Logger
{

  // not needed if you use the WordPress Database    
  private $db_name = 'database';
  private $db_table = 'tablename';
  private $db_user = 'username';
  private $db_password = 'password';
  private $db_host = 'localhost';

  // instance of WordPress' $wpdb
  private static $db = null;

  private static $connection = null;

  public function __construct(){
    if( null === self::$connection )
      $this->connect();
  }

  public function connect(){
    global $wpdb;

    if( null === $this->db )
      $this->db = $wpdb;

    [or connect to another, none WordPress database]
  }

  public function write( $msg = '' ){
    [write message to database]
  }

  public function read( $type = 'all' ){
    [read message)s) from database]
  }

  public function erase( $type = 'all' ){
    [delete message(s) from database]
  }
}
```

Include the class in your php-file and log messages to the database

```
include_once 'path/to/your/class/class-db_logger.php';

$logger = new DB_logger();

[some code]

$logger->write(
  '$var at line ' . __LINE__ . ' in file ' . __FILE__ . ': ' . var_export( $var, TRUE )
);
```

With a bit of PHP and a bit of Ajax you can now periodically request your debbugging infos from the database and display them e.g in the admin bar, header or footer.

FireBug is a great tool, but the debugging infos are lost with the next page reload. Sometimes it could be helpfull to see how things change by changing the code.

Comment: `'$var at line '` won't work.

Comment: __LINE__ does not contain the line where $var is, it return the line where the logger is called. But it is helpfull if you call the logger more than once. I think, if anybody is experienced enough to write a logger class, than he is also experienced enough to understand what __LINE__ will contain.

Comment: I didn't talk about that. It's single vs. double quotes. Single one around `$var` will output ... wait for it ... `$var` and not its contents.

Comment: `'$foo is the name of the variable. It\'s content is: ' . var_export( $foo, true );` vs `"$foo is the name of the variable. It's content is: " . var_export( $foo, true );` ;)

Comment: Rrrrrrright! :)