# Inserting Gravity Form checkbox values into Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, functions, forms, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to feed checkbox values from a Gravity Forms form (which creates a new post) into an Advanced Custom Fields field. I've had a read around and found some info in a post (at the bottom of the question).

Is this the correct way to do it? It's not inserting the multiple GF checkboxes into the ACF textbox. Should I be creating checkboxes with the same options in ACF? Here's my code:

```
add_action("gform_post_submission", "acf_post_submission", 10, 2);

function acf_post_submission ($entry, $form)
{
    $post_id = $entry["post_id"];
    $values = get_post_custom_values("submit_intended", $post_id);  
    update_field("field_23", $values, $post_id);

}
```

I've also tried the following which relates to the screenshots:

```
add_action("gform_post_submission", "checkbox_arrays", 10, 2);
function checkbox_arrays($entry, $form)
{
    $post_id = $entry["post_id"];
    $form_id = $entry["form_id"];

    if ($form_id==3)
    {
        $values = get_post_custom_values("submit_gf_intended", $post_id);
        add_post_meta($post_id, "submit_intended", $values);
    }
}
```

[This post](http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/544/acf-and-gravity-forms/p1) in the advanced custom fields forum may help - http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/discussion/544/acf-and-gravity-forms/p1

I've attached some screenshots too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can't you make a summary of that support thread? Quote the money parts?

Comment: @brasofilo You kinda only need to read the two posts at the bottom by komododan & tyler. It seems they have it working so I must be putting something in wrong. I'll post some screenshots on the question too.

Comment: A Question (or Answer) shouldn't depend on reading external sites, *especially* when they are pages long.

Comment: @brasofilo It's just two posts which I've pointed out. Plus my question includes what I've tried from that post!

Comment: Ok, it's just that I was interpreting "This post...may help" as "Please, read all that to help me". Anyway, back on topic: this [debug technique](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75499/12615) may help.

Comment: Is there actually anything that needs to be done? I just created a custom field in ACF, created a form in GF, added a "custom field", picked the ACF field, saved the form, and added it to a page. I submitted a form post, ticking three boxes, and it saved into the custom field on a new post. Why do you think you need any code at all?

Comment: @webaware it just saves the first checkbox value for me. Is that happening with you? Also, maybe I need to update the plugins - I'm running 3.5.4.1 ACF & 1.6.10.1 GF.

Comment: Is that with, or without, the code you've quoted in your question? I used no additional code, and when I view the custom fields on the new post, it has a value for each checkbox ticked for that field. Using latest versions of WP, ACF, GF.

Comment: @webaware That was without the code. I'll update and see what happens.

Comment: @webaware Ok, I just updated to the latest version of WP, ACF & GF and still the same thing happens. It only checks the first checkbox even though multiple checkboxes are ticked. Is there something obvious in the screenshots that I'm missing? The second screenshot now has the custom field name - submit_intended (i.e the ACF field).

Comment: Interesting, I had it set for no metabox, just changed to using a metabox and it didn't save. Will play some more.

Comment: In fact, it's saving the values into a "regular" custom field of the same name; in the post screen options, view "Custom Fields".

Comment: @webaware I set it to no metabox and still the same problem.

Comment: OK, but are you looking at the "Custom Fields" in the post? The values are saving, just not in the fields that ACF has defined.

Comment: @webaware Yes looking at the post it's created. Hmm, it's strange that it's working for you but not me.

Comment: I think basically, if you define a field "checkboxen" in ACF and tell it to have a metabox, then you need to copy/move the value of that field from "checkboxen" to "_checkboxen" for it to show up in that metabox.

Comment: So, I created a field group called "checkboxen" that has a checkbox field called "checkboxen" and has a metabox. I created a GF with a post title and a custom field; see the [exported form](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26305751/gf-custom-checkboxes.xml). I stuck it on a page. I post a form, it makes a post, the post has a custom field value "checkboxen" for each ticked box. It should be "_checkboxen" to show in the right metabox, but otherwise it worked.

Comment: @webaware I'll give that a go, thanks. 5mins and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @webaware Ok still the same problem! Perhaps if I export my GF & ACF, would you be able to have a look?

Comment: Maybe. Just for the record: if your end-result is to just have a form post to some custom fields, you can do that without ACF; just add a post, add a custom field and give it a name, and GF will then be able to find it in the list of custom fields so that you can post to it. I'm assuming here that you know how to [enable Custom Fields](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26305751/enable-custom-fields.png) in the post editor.

Comment: @webaware Here's my ACF - https://www.dropbox.com/s/m436fc2q0u4xg4s/advanced-custom-field-export.xml (field_23 is the checkboxes) and here's my GF - https://www.dropbox.com/s/g781g4wi1shmy4s/gravityforms-export-2013-01-09%20%281%29.xml

Comment: Too much detail. Can you try the simple case I presented first? (I'm off to dinner now, will look again in the morning)

Comment: @webaware Ok, can you export your ACF to ensure everything is the same?

Comment: Please don't use comments for extensive discussion. You can create a room in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) to do that more conveniently and without piling up comments on question.

Comment: [Done](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/26305751/acf-checkboxen.xml) and off for mango chicken on rice :)

Comment: @webaware Just imported both (thanks for those), it's not ticking the ACF fields in the post. I'll have a play around and see what I can do.

Comment: @webaware Still no luck, it's driving me nuts, its the last thing to do then its complete!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My situation to tackle this problem was a bit problematic because I wanted to use the GF Update Post plugin to let my users edit their post right after they submitted the content. With the above solution ACF does not write to the db and correct ACF fields (at least not for me).

My solution:

1. Create a ACF custom field group and add a field with the same checkboxes and use the same meta_key as your gravity form.
2. Use a function after submission to fetch the all matching keys as array and update the ACF field key (Show on screen -> ACF field value in ACF field group edit screen)

   ```
   add_action("gform_after_submission_YOUR_FORM_ID", "acf_post_submission", 10, 2);

   function acf_post_submission ($entry, $form)
   {
      $post_id = $entry["post_id"];
      $values = get_post_custom_values("YOUR_CUSTOM_FIELD", $post_id);
      update_field("ACF_FIELD_KEY", $values, $post_id);
   }
   ```

Comment: I used the first answer to solve the problem on another site but this didn't require using the data in the post, just capturing it. I'm now working on a new project that requires the post data and your solution worked great.

Comment: Hi @Andy, will this same function apply with a repeater field? I'm trying to follow your steps but I cannot get it working with a repeater.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at this again this morning, and I reckon your problem and solution are both very simple.

NB: using current versions -- WordPress 3.5, Advanced Custom Fields 3.5.7.2, Gravity Forms 1.6.11

First, "ordinary" fields like text fields require no additional effort; create in ACF, create a post that uses it so that it's there to be found by GF, add to a GF form, and use. The value is written to the field. Job is done. No additional code required.

Now, for checkboxes, multiple ticks means multiple values to add to the post. GF does what you expect a sane WordPress plugin to do, it creates multiple entries in the postmeta table. But that's not what ACF wants. When you edit a post and tick multiple checkboxes on an ACF field, what is saved is a single postmeta record with a serialised array. Nice.

So, to "fix" what GF is doing so that it's broken in the way that ACF wants it, get the ID of your form and add a filter to kludge up the post data before GF saves it to postmeta:

```
$formID = 1;    // replace with ID of your form
add_filter("gform_post_data_$formID", 'wpse_78826_gformPostData', 10, 3);

/**
* dirty hack to write checkbox field values as serialised arrays
* to please Advanced Custom Fields, which is _doing_it_wrong()
* @param array $post_data not really the $_POST data, more like a summary of it
* @param array $form the GF form "object"
* @param array $lead the GF lead / entry "object"
* @return array
*/
function wpse_78826_gformPostData($post_data , $form, $lead) {
    $post_data['post_custom_fields']['checkboxen'] = serialize(explode(',', $post_data['post_custom_fields']['checkboxen']));

    return $post_data;
}
```

Job is done. Nasty hack, but ACF is happy at least.

Comment: It didn't work initially but played around with it and got it working. I think the important part is on the GF custom field name I needed to put in "checkboxen" rather than select an existing custom field name created by ACF. It's now working, thanks very much for all the help. You've made me and about 4 other people in the ACF forum very happy!!!

Comment: Excellent! Regarding the field name, GF is looking for an existing post with custom fields to pick up the ACF field name, so it might have been that you had an old one there. Otherwise, brand me clueless. At least you can now get it working :)

Comment: @webaware Your solution work but I'm running into one other problem. This solution saves the data as array and populates the correct checkboxes in the ACF fields. How ever, ACF needs to convert the strings to correct ACF values and this only happens when accessing the admin and a save or publish gets executed by the user. Is there any way to trigger the WP Save automatically? Edit: Sorry, dont know to answer in the correct thread..

Comment: Can you edit this to explain better what "correct ACF values" means? What isn't working? If it's your template, then maybe you'll just need to modify how you're retrieving the values to cope with the fact that the kludged values are in a slightly different format.

Comment: @Andy Please do not use answers for discussion. You will be able to leave [comments](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) when you gain some reputation on site.